# Chrome extension executes when enabled, rather than when clicked

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Here is my manifest.json

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,   

    "name": "PageEscape",
    "version": "1.0",
    "description": "",

    "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"]
    },

    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "escape_icon.png"
    }
}
```

And this is my background.js

```
  chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(window.open("url", "_blank"))
```

My goal is for the user to click on the chrome extension anytime he wants to quickly switch to another page, (of my selection for now) but the problem is that as soon as I enable the extension it goes to the webpage I chose and clicking the extension on the bar does nothing. What can I change here to make this work

Answer (score 1):

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener( function() {
    window.open("url", "_blank");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
var url = 'http://www.example.com/'
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
  openPage(url);
});

/**
 * Open the url specified page, there are three cases:
 * 1. If the page has opened, select it;
 * 2. Else if here is a new tab, open the page in the new tab;
 * 3. Else open a new tab in the current window.
 *
 * @param url
 */
function openPage(url) {
  chrome.tabs.query(function (tabs) {
    var newTab = null;

    // search all tabs
    for (var i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++) {
      var tab = tabs[i];

      if (tab.url === url) {
        chrome.tabs.update(tab.id, {url: url, selected: true});
        return;
      } else if (tab.url === 'chrome://newtab/') {
        newTab = tab;
      }
    }

    if (newTab) {
      chrome.tabs.update(newTab.id, {url: url, selected: true});
    } else {
      chrome.windows.getCurrent(function (win) {
        var winId = win.id;
        chrome.tabs.create({windowId: winId, url: url});
      });
    }
  });
}
```